# Need an Regex for an OrderID

Tags: regex

An letter P followed by a space or an "-" sign.
Then directly followed by an number from 1 until and with 150.
Only full numbers are allowed. Not significant zero's like 01 or 023 are not allowed.
Then directly followed by a dot. And then directly followed by 6 characters from A until and with Z
The P in the beginning and the last 6 characters may be in capital as in lower case.

I am doing something wrong with my range from 1 until 150...Can anyone help me out ?

This is what I got

```
(?i)p[ -]([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1{0,1}[0-5][0-9])[\.][a-z]{6}
```

The regex will find this one too:

```
p 01.SLKDOZ
```

I don't want that...

Comment: While the answer by Njol is correct, I wouldn't check a number range with a regexp. Find the numeric part `(\d+)`, and then check it with arithmetic comparison.

Comment: yeah ...I have read on multiple forums that number range check isnt good with a regex...But int this case its really neccesary its a regex...Some stuff for an assigment! But thanx for the tip bro ! x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `{0,1}` after the 1 (the 1 of 100): `(?i)p[ -]([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-5][0-9])\.[a-z]{6}`

`1{0,1}` matched the 1 zero or one time, and if the 1 isn't matched the following 0 can be matched.

Answer (score 1):

reg.txt

```
p 1.SLKDOZ
P 150.ABCDEF
P 151.ABCDEF
P 150.ABCDEFG
P 090.ABCDEF
P 005.ABCDEF
P 05.ABCDEF
```

Perl regx

```
$ cat reg.txt | perl -nle "chomp($_); print if (/^[pP][- ]([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|150)\.[a-zA-Z]{6}$/g );"
```

Output is :

```
p 1.SLKDOZ
P 150.ABCDEF
```